# Ajax Auto fill not working on dynamic fields but static fields

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dynamic

I had 4 static fields that inserts into Mysql db, when i fill in the first field the other 3 fields gets populated automatically, this works well, but now i had moved over to dynamic fields[] that gets populated by javascript. since the javascript function work with 'id' to autocomplete and fill, it seems that the javascript dynamic fields does not autofill and populate.

Here is the javascript for the dynamic fields:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 30; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append('<table class="table table-bordered"><td><input class="form-control" id="state" type="text" name="name[]" required /></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="surname[]" /></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="idnumber[]" required/></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="uniquenumber[]" required/></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="nominee_photo[]" required/></td></table></div>'); //add input box
            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
    });
```

Here is the form

```
 <form method="post" name="form1" action="ajax.php">
        <div class="input_fields_wrap">
              <button class="add_field_button btn btn-primary btn-flat">Add More users</button>
         </div>
         <div>
             <input class="btn btn-success btn-flat" name="submit" type="submit">
         </div>
             <input type="hidden" name="insert" value="form1">
    </form>
```

Here is the ajax function to autocomplete fields

```
$(function() {

            $('#uniquenumber').val("");
            $('#name').val("");
            $('#surname').val("");

            $('idnumber').autocomplete({
                source: "ajaxpage.php",
                minLength: 4,
                select: function(event, ui) {

                    $('#id').val(ui.item.id);
                    $('#uniquenumber').val(ui.item.uniquenumber);
                    $('#name').val(ui.item.name);
                    $('#surname').val(ui.item.surname);

                },

                response: function(event, ui) {
            // ui.content is the array that's about to be sent to the response callback.
                     if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                     alert("please insert a valid ID Number");
                     $("#empty-message").text("No results found");
            }
                 }
            });


        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a common class as your dummy class instead of id.
then call autocomplete on that :)
i hope this will help you.

Comment: Could you provide a little guideline?

Comment: <input class="form-control your_dummy_class" type="text" name="idnumber[]" required/>$('.your_dummy_class').autocomplete({});

Comment: When i add this class it works on the static text fields but no luck on the dynamic fields. i will keep trying different ideas.

Comment: i think you have to initialize again that plugin.